# What am i missing? You've entered too many arguments for this function - nested IF statement

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I am running into the 'you've entered too many arguments for this function' error and cannot figure out why.  I've got my nested IF statements and the AND statements for the necessary scenarios I need.  But cannot for the life of me figure out what I am missing.  Anybody?

```
=IF(
    HOUSING_PROVIDED = "Yes",
    0,
     IF(
        AND(
            HOUSING_PROVIDED = "No",
            HOUSING_RECALC_YN = "No",
            PRIOR_EXCESS_HOUSING <= 0
        ),
        0,
         IF(
            AND(
                HOUSING_PROVIDED = "No",
                HOUSING_RECALC_YN = "No",
                PRIOR_EXCESS_HOUSING > 0
            ),
            PRIOR_EXCESS_HOUSING,
             IF(
                AND(
                    HOUSING_PROVIDED = "No",
                    HOUSING_RECALC_YN = "Yes",
                    DUAL_CAREER_YN = "No",
                    EXCESS_HOUSING = "Yes"
                ),
                EXCESS_HOUSING,
                 IF(
                    AND(
                        HOUSING_PROVIDED = "No",
                        HOUSING_RECALC_YN = "Yes",
                        DUAL_CAREER_YN = "No",
                        EXCESS_HOUSING = "No",
                        HOUSING_RENTAL_LIMIT > 0
                    ),
                    HOUSING_RENTAL_LIMIT,
                     IF(
                        AND(
                            HOUSING_PROVIDED = "No",
                            HOUSING_RECALC_YN = "Yes",
                            DUAL_CAREER_YN = "No",
                            EXCESS_HOUSING = "No",
                            HOUSING_RENTAL_LIMIT <= 0
                        ),
                        "Run Data Calc",
                         IF(
                            AND(
                                HOUSING_PROVIDED = "No",
                                HOUSING_RECALC_YN = "Yes",
                                DUAL_CAREER_YN = "Yes",
                                SPOUSE_POLICY <> "Core",
                                EXCESS_HOUSING = "Yes"
                            ),
                            EXCESS_HOUSING,
                             IF(
                                AND(
                                    HOUSING_PROVIDED = "No",
                                    HOUSING_RECALC_YN = "Yes",
                                    DUAL_CAREER_YN = "Yes",
                                    SPOUSE_POLICY <> "Core",
                                    EXCESS_HOUSING = "Yes"
                                ),
                                HOUSING_RENTAL_LIMIT > 0,
                                HOUSING_RENTAL_LIMIT,
                                 IF(
                                    AND(
                                        HOUSING_PROVIDED = "No",
                                        HOUSING_RECALC_YN = "Yes",
                                        DUAL_CAREER_YN = "Yes",
                                        SPOUSE_POLICY <> "Core",
                                        EXCESS_HOUSING = "Yes"
                                    ),
                                    HOUSING_RENTAL_LIMIT <= 0,
                                    "Run Data Calc",
                                     IF(
                                        AND(
                                            HOUSING_PROVIDED = "No",
                                            HOUSING_RECALC_YN = "Yes",
                                            DUAL_CAREER_YN = "Yes",
                                            SPOUSE_POLICY = "Core",
                                            DUAL_CAREER_LOWER_YN = "Yes"
                                        ),
                                        0,
                                         IF(
                                            AND(
                                                HOUSING_PROVIDED = "No",
                                                HOUSING_RECALC_YN = "Yes",
                                                DUAL_CAREER_YN = "Yes",
                                                SPOUSE_POLICY = "Core",
                                                DUAL_CAREER_LOWER_YN = "No",
                                                EXCESS_HOUSING = "Yes"
                                            ),
                                            EXCESS_HOUSING,
                                             IF(
                                                AND(
                                                    HOUSING_PROVIDED = "No",
                                                    HOUSING_RECALC_YN = "Yes",
                                                    DUAL_CAREER_YN = "Yes",
                                                    SPOUSE_POLICY = "Core",
                                                    DUAL_CAREER_LOWER_YN = "No",
                                                    HOUSING_RENTAL_LIMIT > 0
                                                ),
                                                HOUSING_RENTAL_LIMIT,
                                                 IF(
                                                    AND(
                                                        HOUSING_PROVIDED = "No",
                                                        HOUSING_RECALC_YN = "Yes",
                                                        DUAL_CAREER_YN = "Yes",
                                                        SPOUSE_POLICY = "Core",
                                                        DUAL_CAREER_LOWER_YN = "No",
                                                        HOUSING_RENTAL_LIMIT <= 0
                                                    ),
                                                    "Run Data Calc",
                                                    "Dont Run Data Calc"
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Ever thought of maybe *not* using Excel? Because that’s what a sane person does.

Comment: I wish it were that easy... but required for work and what I'm trying to achieve here is spreadsheet based.

Comment: That’s great and all, but most things are not really *required*. You can also work out a better solution. Incidentally, Excel also supports VBA. Or maybe create a hidden sheet. Or ten. Anything is better than cramming a whopping 125 lines of code into a single cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read this correctly, the following `IF()` call has 4 arguments:

```
 IF(
    AND(
        HOUSING_PROVIDED = "No",
        HOUSING_RECALC_YN = "Yes",
        DUAL_CAREER_YN = "Yes",
        SPOUSE_POLICY <> "Core",
        EXCESS_HOUSING = "Yes"
    ),
    HOUSING_RENTAL_LIMIT > 0,
    HOUSING_RENTAL_LIMIT,
     IF(
        ...
    )
)
```

It starts at line 53 in the expanded code.

There is another statement, starting at line 63, that also has 4 arguments:

```
 IF(
    AND(
        HOUSING_PROVIDED = "No",
        HOUSING_RECALC_YN = "Yes",
        DUAL_CAREER_YN = "Yes",
        SPOUSE_POLICY <> "Core",
        EXCESS_HOUSING = "Yes"
    ),
    HOUSING_RENTAL_LIMIT <= 0,
    "Run Data Calc",
     IF(
        ...
    )
)
```

But seriously man, don’t do this. You won’t ever be able to revise this, starting from as early as the day after tomorrow. Simply because you won’t be able to understand why you did it and how and maybe even what. ;)

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the feedback.  Ya i may end up just creating a table of the data and using a vlookup to match my necessary scenarios.  The spreadsheet feeds our underlying software to run some calculations so I am stuck with excel but ya i definitely feel it was a bit extreme with the 125 lines.  Thanks for checking for me. Jason

Comment: Sounds like your business should go for an appropriate software instead, where you can define the rules you want inside, instead of having to rely on wonky Excel formulas spitting out magic strings.